# Counting Sort - I know how it works but Unable to solve it

Tags: sorting, counting, counting-sort

If certain conditions are fullfilled, counting-sort can sort in linear time. Construct a
sequence A =< a1; : : : ; a10 > of n = 10 numbers where counting-sort needs theta(n^7) time. Explain your choice.

my approach ;

If i select A = [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,2], where n=10
C new would be [3,4,6,7,8,9,10] and B =[ 0,0,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,6]
This is how counting sort works (according to lectures) but how do i prove it has run time of n power 7? by calculating run time of each step according to pseudo code and then adding?

Comment: Seems like a question posed to you posted here as is.

Comment: Yes, coz i know how counting sort works and i tried using as below;
If i select A = [0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,2], where n=10
C new would be [3,4,6,7,8,9,10] and B =[ 0,0,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,6]
This is how counting sort works (according to lectures) but how do i prove it has run time of n power 7? by calculating run time of each step according to pseudo code and then adding?

Comment: This question seems like it's not possible to solve because Theta notation talks about the runtime in the limit as a function of n, so having a fixed n and a fixed sequence where the runtime is Theta(n^7) shouldn't be possible. The runtime is O(1) for any fixed size and sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Select A[] so that the range is n^7, in this case, 10^7. It could be A[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9999999};. Since the counting array size is 10^7, a single scan over the array to produce the output will take 10^7 loops.

Comment: Waow.. Make sense,,, A perfect answer. Thank you alot!!! I discussed with my professor too and he said same..Thank you again!